# Finding the max sum of elements in matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

If I have the matrix like this one:

```
135 90 45 0

46  0  0  0

120 90 60 30

74  37 0  0
```

How can I choose elements from the matrix without repeating rows and columns? For example: in this matrix i have to choose: `135-37-60-0 => 232`. What kind of algorithm can implement that?

Comment: what do you mean "from massive"?

Comment: Ok, sorry from matrix

Comment: depth-first-search is always a winner.

Comment: Do they have to be chosen at random?

Comment: No, it doesnt matter, we just need the max sum

Comment: @barry, you mean to use it like graph?

Comment: Why don't you just loop through it?

Comment: @Jared Wadsworth, no i cant, I have time limit